# c++ error: assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'const char *'

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with a programming assignment for my c++ class and I am not sure how I should be doing this to not get an error. I am pretty new to programming, so this will probably be really easy.

In my instructions, we have to create a class to work with other code that is given to us with some guidelines. I have three files: program.h, program.cpp, and main.cpp.

program.h

```
//program.h
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdint.h>\\This program uses type uint32_t so had to include this
#include <cstdlib>

class Program
{
   public:
   Program(); //was told to create a default constructor to initiate values if none are given
   Program(char *, uint32_t, float); //was told to create an overloaded default constructor to change variables in program
   void SetName ( const char* ); //given by the professor
//other function prototypes are here but they are working fine.

   private:
   char * name_; //given by professor
   uint32_t code_;//given by professor
   float cost_;//given by professor

   
};
```

program.cpp

```
//program.cpp
//other functions from class are in this file, just not giving any issues
Program::Program(char * name,uint32_t code, float cost) : name_(name), code_(code), cost_(cost)
{
}

Program::Program() : name_(NULL), code_(0x00000000), cost_(0.0)
{
}
void Program::SetName(const char* name)
{
   name_= name; //where the issue appears to occur since name is a const char *
}
```

currently trying to compile program.o using makefile and program.h program.cpp so the main.cpp does not matter. When i try to compile, i receive the following error:

> clang++ -oprogram.h program.cpp
> program.cpp:17:9: error: assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'const char *'
>
> name_ = name;

Since the function was void SetName (const char*); was given by the professor and has to be used. I am not sure how to fix this error since the variable char * name_; was also given to us by the professor. Pointers still confuse me some, but any help would be greatly appreciated. I always thought that constant data can be passed to nonconstant data but not vise versa.

Comment: are you sure you have to set the pointer in `SetName` ? You may be supposed to copy the string pointed to by `const char* name`

Comment: Create enough space to store name and copy name to name_.   Don't forget to add the string terminator. If you just assign it, when name goes out of scope, you will get garbage in name_.  Just remember to create a destructor and delete it in the destructor.

Comment: So many syntax errors I don't know where to start. This is not your real code!

Comment: You're not showing valid c++ code in your question. Start [fixing this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32684513/edit) first please!

Comment: Important note: `name_= name;` Both name_ and name are pointers to data, not data. Assigning one to the other has both pointing to the same memory block. If you use one pointer to change the memory block, you change both. If one releases the memory block, it is gone for both. Even without the compiler error, you really, really do not want to do this.

Comment: The instruction for the SetName function states to set the name field.

Comment: Sorry for the code errors. I renamed the class and a few other things. I did not notice the name_=name both being pointers. Am I understanding wrongly based on the instructions I was given on what the SetName function is supposed to do??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cryptic error message when passing const parameters as arguments](/q/19423688/90527)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Important point just to get this out of the way:

```
 char * name_;
```

Defines a pointer to a character. This just makes a pointer. It does not make a character. You will need to provide the character that is pointed at later. This pointer can be used to change the memory at which it points.

```
const char* name
```

Defines a pointer to a character that *cannot be changed*.

A value that cannot be changed is fundamentally different from a value that can be changed. You can copy the unchangeable value into the changable, but you cannot do the reverse because that would require changing the unchangeable value.

A pointer that can be used to change a value cannot be pointed at an unchangeable value to prevent the obvious problem of using the pointer to attempt to change the value.

What you need to do is copy.

But first, you need to allocate storage to hold the copy. This should be covered by your text, leaving one problem: How much storage is needed?

First, you have to know what a [string is and how they are represented in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling). Not C++, but C. C++ does it a little bit differently and your professor will get to that eventually. I hope. God, I really hope. In the meantime, the professor has you working with C-style strings.

[strlen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) solves the how much storage problem, mostly. `strlen` will tell you the length of a properly formatted string of characters. What it doesn't tell you is implied by the definition of a character string. Hope you read the link.

Now that you know how much storage you need, you allocate the storage with `new`.

Now that you have a `name_` pointing to enough storage, you can copy from the constant memory at `name` into it. [strcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) should be helpful here.

This is wonderful, but leave you with a small problem: what if there already was  storage at `_name`? Shucks. We just overwrote the pointer to it. This is called a memory leak and is no small part of why C++ does strings differently.

OK, so before allocating storage for `name_`and copying the storage at `name` into it, first you need to test to make sure `name_` is empty. Couple of ways to do this:

1. Set a canary value. A canary is an impossible value; something that you will never see. Typically for pointers we use NULL, a glorified 0. There is nothing at address zero by convention, so if you see a pointer pointing to zero something is up. If in the constructor you make sure that `name_` is NULL, you will have an easy way to know if `name_` isn't pointing at data yet.
2. Keep a length value and set it to zero in the constructor. If the length is zero, there's nothing there. As an added bonus since this allow you to know the length of your storage, you can compare it to the amount of storage needed by the new string. If the new string is the same size or smaller, you can write over the old string.

If you need to replace `name_`'s storage, `delete[]` the old storage before allocating new storage.

Putting it all together, and using option 2 because it's better, you get:

```
int len = strlen(name)
if len > length_
    delete name_
    name_ = new storage
strcpy(name_, name)
```

Note there are a few pieces missing you'll have to fill out.

And just to be an ass, this is what all that would look like with C++ strings:

```
name_ = name;
```

Look familiar? Aren't you glad your professor decided to teach you to program in C++ the worst, hardest way first?

Comment: Thank you for your response. This sounds like the way i have to go, but can i ask one more question? What makes this a c-style string versus a c++ style string? In my book, the examples it gives only have int variable; in private and not a pointer like in this program I am having to work on. Is that what makes this a c style string?

Comment: @user5356976 A C-style array is is covered in one of the links. Read it. It will save you a lot of trouble. A [C++ string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), `std::string`, is a class that (most likely) surrounds a C-style string with all the memory management you'll need and a collection of utility methods to make common string manipulation as easy as possible. Combining two strings in C is the same sort of mess as above (allocate space, copy in string one, copy in string two) and with std::string it's `string three = one + two;` All the monkey work is done for you.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some typos. You have space in

```
#include < iostream >
```

Remove the space

```
#include <iostream>
```

Change char to

```
   const char * name_;
```

Add semicolon after the last } in the Program class definition.

Example on the code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "program.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;

    char const * name = "Claus";
    uint32_t code = 1967;
    float cost (3.14f);

    Program p (name, code, cost);
    cout << "getName(): " << p.getName() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

program.cpp

```
#include "program.h"

Program::Program() {};
Program::~Program() {};
Program::Program(char const * name,uint32_t code, float cost) : name_(name), code_(code), cost_(cost) {}

void Program::SetName(const char* name) {
   name_= name; //where the issue appears to occur since name is a const char *
}

char const* Program::getName() {
    return name_;
}
```

program.h

```
#ifndef PROGRAM_H
#define PROGRAM_H

#include <stdint.h>

class Program {
public:
    Program(); //was told to create a default constructor to initiate values if none are given
    ~Program();
    Program(const char * , uint32_t, float); //was told to create an overloaded default constructor to change variables in program
    void SetName (const char* );
    const char* getName();

private:
    const char * name_;
    unsigned int code_;
    float cost_;

};

#endif // PROGRAM_H
```

On my mac I compile it with

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o main main.cpp program.cpp
```

I get warning about unused variables but that's OK.

I was inspired by user4581301's response to learn a bit C. C++ does alleviate it alot.

In program.cpp

```
Program::Program(char * name, uint32_t code, float cost) {
    unsigned int len = strlen(name);
    name_ = new char[len];
    strcpy(name_, name);

    code_ = code;
    cost_ = cost;
}

void Program::SetName(const char* name) {
    unsigned int len = strlen(name);
    delete name_;
    name_ = new char[len];
    strcpy(name_, name);
}
```

This link helped me as well: [how to initialize a char pointer in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283084/how-to-initialize-a-char-pointer-in-a-class)

regards
Claus

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am still looking into the first response. You did find a few typos i missed by accident when i retyped it on here (first time posting on here), however changing the private: variable from char * name_; to const char * name_; is not a typo, that is in the instructions the professor gave. I am looking into the first response with strcpy right now as i do not have any other solutions. The programs are graded by a program created by the professor, so i cannot change anything that he gave us unfortunately without the program that grades what we turn in freaking out.

Comment: I was in my own context, char name_ was OK, not a typo.